# How to install Python libraries on Windows without UAC?

Tags: python

So I downloaded the Python embedded files, and put it into %USERPROFILE%\bin\python to run Python files.
Then I downloaded setuptools files from PyPI and tried to install setuptools by using “Python setuptools install”, but it give me the “No module named ‘setuptools’” error.
Is there any way I can install Python libraries on Windows without UAC? Thanks.

Comment: What are the "Python embedded files"? (What exactly did you download?) Why not just install Python from the .msi installer? I'm pretty sure it allows "install for this user only" which shouldn't require UAC escalation.

Answer (score 0):

I do it the following way:

1. Download the `whl` file from [PyPi](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/02/8d4d27b1cacaac2d129a27d17a22d92a2a5eedcb7817d4ed8ab0d4daf5c4/setuptools-60.9.3-py3-none-any.whl)
2. Open powershell and change to the directory where the `whl` file is located.
3. Run `pip install setuptools-<version-info>.whl`